# Error after updating dnvm to 1.0.0-rc1-final

Tags: c#, asp.net, dnvm

After updating dnvm from `beta8` to `1.0.0-rc1-final` I had an error in my `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(); <======= "iservicecollection does not contain a definition for add mvc(error)"
        services.AddTransient<IRepository, MongoRepository>();
    }
```

my project.json:

```
{
  "packExclude": "*.cmd",
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.22",
    "RestSharp": "105.2.3",
    "mongocsharpdriver": "2.1.0"
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5001",
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5505",
    "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Drawing": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Drawing.Design": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "bundleExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.kproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

What i did wrong? Thanks you. If i just comment line:

```
services.AddMvc();
```

I had this error: http://clip2net.com/clip/m446898/72b2d-clip-21kb.png?nocache=1

Answer (score 2):

The `Microsoft.Framework` libraries are now `Microsoft.Extensions`.

For example, `Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc` is now `Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following on and expanding a bit on Joel's answer:

I just had this issue.

In the command prompt, i ran `dnvm upgrade` to update my DNX.

**NOTE**: Make sure visual studio is closed when you run this. I had it open and it just would **not** work after i did the stuff below. I had a `IApplicationBuilder exists in both Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions and Microsoft.AspNet.Http` error because of it. So i ended up restarting my pc, and then everything worked. So maybe restart your pc, then do the following.

Switched it all to `rc1-final` version.

I changed my `global.json` to this:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  }
}
```

My `project.json` dependencies section looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
},
```

Notice the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, not `Microsoft.Framework`

Right click on 'References' and select 'Restore Packages'. Do this after any project.json change.

Then in my `Startup.cs` file, i changed the reference from `Microsoft.Framework` to `Microsoft.Extensions`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;


public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    }

}
```